# Qt OpenSSL problem - blocked (?) on some computers

Tags: qt, ssl, webkit, openssl, qtnetwork

I write an app i qt which uses OpenSSL. All was alright, since yesterday. I compiled app and sent to my friend. On his computer application can open https. I open on other computer and it doesn't work. So I gave it to other friend and he can't open https websites. I was confused and gave other guy and on his computer my app is working. I don't understand situation. Previous versions worked without bugs. But i ran previous version which worked and it doesn't work too. I turned off all my firewalls. Nothing changed.

Any suggestions?

We all have 7 x64. I tested on XP HE and it works, bou on 7 x64 doesn't work. On my friend's computer 7 x64 works, but on XP HE doesn't works. IMO Operating System hasn't got any mean.

Comment: It will help if you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work".  A specific error would be useful.

Comment: https not load. When I send a request to SSL page it returns blank page. My faut, I didn't explain "doesn't work"

Answer (score 2):

By default Qt doesn't contain implementation of OpenSSL, but uses libraries already installed into system.

Installing [Win32 OpenSSL](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) will make it work.

Another option is to build Qt with OpenSSL. Some info [here](http://blog.simpleit.us/2010/05/30/enabling-openssl-for-qt-c-on-windows/).

Comment: I build Qt with OpenSSL. What's more on my PC OpenSSL is instaled but my app doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`QSslSocket::ignoreSslErrors()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/qsslsocket.html#ignoreSslErrors) method.

I also had such problems and using this function solved them for me.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have still no solution to the error - I just ran over the same issue. It seems to be a problem with the CA certficate chain on the Windows computer. The details can be found at https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-20012.

Here's also a little class which fixes the ca chain so the error should not occur in the application.

```
#ifndef OPENSSLFIX_H
#define OPENSSLFIX_H

#include <QSslConfiguration>

/* this class fixes a problem with qt/openssl and expired ca certificates.
 * the idea is taken from https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-20012
 * which describes the problem and the workaround further. the workaround is
 * scheduled for qt5, but will not be introduced into qt4.x.
 *
 * to use this fix just call it in main() before doing any network related 
 * stuff
 *
 * OpenSslFix::fixCaCertificates();
 *
 * it will go through the certificates and remove invalid certs from the chain,
 * thus avoiding the error to arise.
 */
class OpenSslFix {
public:
    static void fixCaCertificates()
    {
        QSslConfiguration config(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
        QList<QSslCertificate> in(config.caCertificates());
        QList<QSslCertificate> out;

        for (int i=0, size=in.size(); i<size; ++i) {
            const QSslCertificate &c(in[i]);
            if (c.isValid()) {
                /* not expired -> add */
                out << c;
                continue;
            }

            /* check if the cert is already present in the output */
            bool found = false;
            for (int j=0, size=out.size(); j<size; ++j) {
                if (isCertificateSameName(c, out[j])) {
                    /* already present... */
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
                out << c;
        }

        /* now set the new list as the default */
        config.setCaCertificates(out);
        QSslConfiguration::setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }

private:
    static inline bool isCertificateSameName(const QSslCertificate &cert1, 
                                             const QSslCertificate &cert2)
    {
        return cert1.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::Organization) ==
                cert2.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::Organization) &&
                cert1.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::CommonName) ==
                cert2.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::CommonName) &&
                cert1.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::LocalityName) ==
                cert2.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::LocalityName) &&
                cert1.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::OrganizationalUnitName) ==
                cert2.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::OrganizationalUnitName) &&
                cert1.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::StateOrProvinceName) ==
                cert2.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::StateOrProvinceName) &&
                cert1.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::CountryName) ==
                cert2.subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::CountryName);
    }
};

#endif // OPENSSLFIX_H
```